# Выбор сервера БД для работы с Android

Tags: android, jdbc, sql-server, sql, mysql

Добрый день. Не так давно занимаюсь разработкой под андроид, по сему возникла проблема. Необходимо на компе в локальной сети развернуть сервер с БД и с андроида дергать оттуда данные. Таблицы будут содержать различные поля в основном текст, но одно из полей это изображение. Собственно посоветуйте как лучше все это дело организовать? Развернуть MS SQL Server хранить изображение в BLOB,ах? но не возникнет ли потом проблемы при распаковки на клиенте в андроиде? Есть еще вариант MySQl + обертка на PHP, после запроса отсылать данные в JSON, но тут опять не понятно как быть с изображениями? В общем прошу совета в какую сторону лучше копать?

Спасибо, заранее.

Comment: Картинки можно шифровать в base64, хранить в БД, а потом в json передавать.
Ну а уже потом base64_decode;

Comment: мне кажется, андроид в этом вопросе не при чем. Андноид-клиент должен общаться не с базой данных, а с API сервера, который вытащит/добавить все что нужно в базу, и приведет ответ к нужному для Андроид-приложения виду. Так что выбирайте базу опираясь на то, как думаете писать API. А если вздумаете сделать общение приложения напрямую с базой, я лично найду ваше приложение, и дропну базу))

Answer (score 3):

Только мое имхо, не претендую на истину в последней инстанции -  хранить изображение в sqlite не рекомендуется, на сервере тоже под большим вопросом, лучше просто хранить ссылку на на изображение пусть приложение само их докачивает. Что выбрать ? - для клиента в сущности без разницы, общение между серверной частью все равно через api.  
Если очень хочется картинку можно закодировать в строку и отправлять в JSON, но зачастую важно отобразить текстовую информацию а картинку можно и в другом потоке подгрузить.

Answer (score 0):

Имхо, `SQLite` будет удачным решением. Картинки хранить отдельно на файловой системе (можно в сжатом виде), а в БД путь к ним.
Все же BLOB, это путь смелых и хорошо понимающих в том, что они делают.

Comment: вопрос был про серверную часть, а если клиентов много? при всех достоинствах SQLite не советовал бы ее использовать на сервере для такой задачи (хотя если для локальной сети где будет один клиент не критично, но тот же mysql сделает все тоже самое, но при увеличение числа клиентов не упадет )

Comment: спасибо что поправили, я действительно не заметил что речь не о клиенте. Поставьте минус плз.